# Random Number Issue C#

Tags: c#, random, numbers

I am learning to use C# at the moment, and am just making random things I think of, so basically this is a "credit card generator" which obviously doesn't make real card numbers, just a random 16 digit number, with the CVV and Exp date.

So far, I can get it to print the Exp date, but as for the credit card number, I am getting an error which says -

"Cannot convert from long to int" and also a message stating the best overloaded method.

I am also having some problems with the date function, I can get it to generate 6 numbers ok, eg, day and year, but if i try to add another 2 numbers, it spits out 6 still.

Here is my code, sorry if this makes no sense, like I said, I am new to this :)

Thanks in advance for any help.

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {


        Random rnd = new Random();
        double cardNumber = rnd.Next(4572000000000000, 4999999999999999);
        int cvv = rnd.Next(001, 999);
        int expDay = rnd.Next(1, 30);
        int expMonth = rnd.Next(1, 12);
        int expYear = rnd.Next(2011, 2015);

        textBox1.Text = cardNumber.ToString();
        textBox2.Text = cvv.ToString();
        textBox3.Text = expDay.ToString() + expMonth.ToString() + expYear.ToString();

    }
```

I will say this again just to make this clear, this in no way makes real credit card numbers, they are just randomly generated digits.....

Comment: `4572000000000000` is too big for **int**

Answer (score 2):

`Random.Next` takes `int`. Since `4999999999999999` and `4572000000000000` are larger than `int.MaxValue` (`2147483647`) but less than `long.MaxValue` (`9223372036854775807`) they are automatically treated as indicating you want a `long` (as if you'd put an `L` on the end), but that can't be turned back into a number between `-2147483648` and `2147483647`. And that wouldn't be much use to you if it could.

You could produce a series of shorter numbers and add them together.

For greater verisimilitude, you could produce one less numbers than you need for your credit-card number (typically 16, so you'd produce 15 numbers, though card numbers from 14-digit to 19-digit have been used in the past) and then do a reverse Luhn to produce the final number, so you'd have a valid credit card number that passed a Luhn check. (This even has a practical use; it can be useful to special-case a Luhn-valid number outside of the range used by any real card issuer in debug-builds, so that you've a test number that most of your code treats as a valid number, but the final step knows not to try to purchase anything with).

Comment: Thanks very much, I did kind of as you said and just generated 4 strings of random numbers to give me 16 digits and joined them.

I have no clue how to work anything to do with Luhn, but hopefully someday I will be at that level of programming :)

Comment: Luhn isn't a bad exercise for someone learning to code. It's a checksum used on credit/debit/other banking cards to catch typos before processing: The last digit can be calculated from the rest, so if that doesn't work the chances are the user made a mistake, and we can catch that before we try to process the card. As well as having practical uses, it's pretty simple but a bit more complicated than most of the code that just demonstrates a given language feature, so give it a go! …

Comment: Read the first bit in https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Luhn_algorithm and see if you can do it. If stuck, look at the Python code toward the bottom of that page and see if it can serve as pseudo-code to guide you in your C# version.
Then afterwards you can change your random card generator to either promise only valid numbers (pass Luhn) or only invalid numbers (don't pass Luhn, therefore doesn't match any real card; the credit-card equivalent of a 555 phone number).

Answer (score 0):

As others have stated, the issue is that int doesn't work with numbers that big. As you say that you are just playing around and not creating real card numbers, what about creating a loop to create a single digit, then calling that 16 times. Each time you call the function, you can append the result to a string and hold that value for later.

Also, I don't think anyone has pointed it out yet, but you are using `double` as the type for your card number. That is an imprecise data type, and would not be appropriate here, where you need a precise number. the value you want may be 1234567891234567, but what is actually stored in memory is 123456789123456.0000000000001.

```
Random rnd = new Random();
string cardNumber = string.Empty;

for(int i = 0; i < 16; i++)
{
    cardNumber += rnd.Next(0,9).ToString();
}
```

Comment: Thanks very much, I was actually thinking about using a loop, but couldn't figure out how to.

Answer (score 0):

This is the code I am using now, but I want to take a look at the loop as suggested above, it seems a much cleaner solution.

```
        Random rnd = new Random();
        int cardNumber1 = rnd.Next(4572, 4999);
        int cardNumber2 = rnd.Next(1000, 9999);
        int cardNumber3 = rnd.Next(1000, 9999);
        int cardNumber4 = rnd.Next(1000, 9999);
        int cvv = rnd.Next(100, 999);
        int expDay = rnd.Next(1, 30);
        int expMonth = rnd.Next(1, 12);
        int expYear = rnd.Next(2015, 2019);

        textBox1.Text = cardNumber1.ToString() + cardNumber2.ToString() + cardNumber3.ToString() + cardNumber4.ToString();
        textBox2.Text = cvv.ToString();
        textBox3.Text = expDay.ToString() + "/" + expMonth.ToString() + "/" + expYear.ToString();
```